# Simple TCP proxy in Vert.x using Pump class (JAVA)

Tags: java, asynchronous, tcp, proxy, vert.x

I would like to realize a proof of concept TCP transparent proxy in Vert.x.

### Requirement

A verticle that listens on port X and when somebody connects and sends data it opens a client connection towards a preconfigured TCP server.
From this moment until any of the peers closes the connection, a bidirectional channel is kept and data flows up and down the channel from client to server and viceversa.

Here's my attempt which is not working.

```
 vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler(new Handler<NetSocket>() {
        public void handle(final NetSocket socket) {
            vertx.createNetClient().connect(6367, "localhost", new Handler<NetSocket>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(NetSocket cliSocket) {
                    Pump.createPump(socket, cliSocket);
                    Pump.createPump(cliSocket, socket);

                }
            });     
    }
    }).listen(3000);
}
```

At least this is how I understood the meaning of the Pump class:

http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#pump

Where's my error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just was missing to start the pumps. Then it worked.

```
Pump.createPump(socket, cliSocket).start();
Pump.createPump(cliSocket, socket).start();
```